# PowerPoint for Mac: how to set video to auto-stop on bookmark?

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a video on a PowerPoint slide. During the presentation, it can be started with a mouse click. How can I set it to *automatically* stop at a checkpoint, after which it can be resumed with another click?

I am using PowerPoint version 16.16.4 on macOS. Is it possible to do this with PowerPoint for Mac? I found [tutorials for Windows](https://lucpowerpoint.blogspot.com/2016/12/automatically-pause-video-at-specific.html) but I do not see the necessary GUI (the "Trigger" button) in the Mac version. I am able to set a bookmark, to add a "pause" step to the animations list, but I can only set the "pause" step to start "on click", "with previous", "after previous" within the Timing section of the Animations pane.

Comment: Can you get someone with a Windows version of PPT to set this up for you as a test? I suspect that the Mac version, while lacking the UI to set triggers, will still respect them if set in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

you want to add bookmarks to the video, then add a trigger in the animation tab to "pause" after the bookmark has been reached. then add one "pause" action on a click trigger. its a bit unintuitive, since the "play" action restarts the video. but the "pause" action will resume an already paused video.

Comment: Can you please be specific about where the GUI controls are for these? I do not know how to add a trigger. I see no buttons labelled "trigger" on the Animation tab. Are you using PowerPoint for Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a Microsoft web page claiming that this feature on macOS is only available to Mac users with a 365 subscription, not with the one-time payment version.

Here's a workaround:
Instead of using several bookmarks inside one video on one slide, chop the entire video into several slices and make them play on every new slide. To do so, use the trimming feature within Powerpoint. Shorten the video to the first point where your want it to pause. Then on the next slide trim the video so it starts off from the previous trimming point. Then make it play automatically when changing to the new slide. So every slide in Powerpoint plays only a fraction of the entire video.